# Как заменить нулями данные в середине бинарного файла?

Tags: linux, sh

Есть ли стандартная для RedHat команда (кроме пары dd + truncate) для замены нулями данных в середине бинарного файла?

Comment: если надо заменить **все** символы, можно воспользоваться программой *tr* (восьмиричное 377 — это десятичное 255): `$ cat файл1 | tr '\1-\377' '\0' > файл2`

Comment: Может `bvi` поможет?

Comment: @donRumata, `bvi` это что такое?

Comment: @avp, согласно описанию в репе от бубунты - это vim-like редактор бинарных файлов. Сам не ковырял, но вспомнил, что такая штука есть, когда увидел твой вопрос. http://bvi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @donRumata, спасибо. В таком случае `emacs` также подходит. Думал, раз в вопросе упомянуты `dd` и `truncate`, то очевидно, что речь об использовании в скрипте (конечно, при желании и редактор можно из скрипта попользовать)

Comment: @avp, ну про скриптинг я понял сразу, но раз вим умеет неинтерактивный режим, то наверняка и `bvi` обязан уметь.

Comment: С этим справится *dd*  безо всяких truncate.

Comment: @0andriy, отлично. Напишите ответ, аналогичный ответу от Abyx (как заменить 4 байта со смещением 123 на нули)

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=file1 bs=1 seek=123 count=4 conv=notrunc` — если сработает, могу оформить в ответ. Если *любым* наперёд заданным байтом, то таки придётся `tr` звать, да: `tr '\0' '\0NNN' /dev/zero | dd if=- ...`

Comment: @0andriy, да, такой `dd` работает также, как и однострочник на python (а у вас \*nix-ов нет под рукой?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать однострочник на Python или другом скриптовом языке:

```
python -c "f=open('some','r+b');f.seek(123);f.write('\0'*4);"
```

Comment: Результирующая длина сохряняется? Проверьте на файлах больше 4к.

Comment: @0andriy, да, все ОК. А в чем причина сомнений?

Comment: @avp не следует двоичные файлы в текстовом режиме открывать. `with open('file.bin', 'r+b') as f:  f.seek(123); f.write(b'\0'*4)` хотя для этого `dd` достаточно. В zsh есть sysseek. `<>` позволяет file для чтения и записи открыть.

Comment: @jfs, Почему? Я проверял в Ubuntu и RedHat. Работает.

Comment: @avp это "undefined behavior" в seek передавать значения не из tell(), если 'b' не выставить. К чему в особенности реализации вдаваться, если можно получить гарантированное документированное переносимое поведение, если 'b' добавить.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, подправлю скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

В копилку.

**Emacs** поддерживает работу с бинарными файлами, как с обычными:

```
M-x hexl-find-file
```

открыть файл в шестнациричном формате

```
C-M-d
```

вставить байт в десятичном формате.

```
C-M-o
```

вставить байт в восмиричном формате

```
C-M-x
```

вставить байт в шестнацитиричном формате

**Ссылки**

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html

Comment: Да. А также для ввода любых символов (в обычном режиме) можно использовать команду `(quoted-insert)` (обычно привязана к `Ctrl-q`), вводя код байта  в системе счисления, заданной в переменной `read-quoted-char-radix` (по умолчанию 8)